# Could this have oxidized the beer?

Tags: fermentation, oxidation

While getting a sample of beer for a hydrometer reading, I squeezed the turkey baster while it was in the beer, so it caused a bunch of bubbles. I did that twice.

Anything to worry about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *'Anything to worry about?'*

Really, it's nothing to worry about at all.

> *'Could this have oxidized the beer?'*

Sure, technically, but to a really negligible amount.

How much this *might* effect the beer depends on when during fermentation/conditioning this was. During primary it's really inconsequential. During conditioning may be *a tiny bit* worse since the beer isn't vigorously evolving CO<sub>2</sub> to push away any introduced oxygen. But still, it won't make a huge (or probably even noticeable difference) in the end product.

Home-brew tends to be consumed fast enough to make this kind of oxidation a non-issue. I appreciate worrying about it from a 'best-practice' kind of standpoint, and so (especially since you identify the potential downsides of what happened) you can, of course, try to avoid it in the future. But it really isn't something that should be of huge concern.